# Issue using CoreData with Codable protocol

Tags: swift, core-data, decodable

I created two `NSManagedObject` classes one for `Songs` and one for `Categories` of each song. And they have a one to many relationship. What i do is that i download a `json` file from the server and parse it using `Decodable` and save the data in CoreData. Every thing is smooth except when i try to add songs to a certain category type i get a crash.

> 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'category' between objects in different contexts

I know what this crash is and i know i have two context one for the category class and one for the song class. The issue is that tutorials for CoreData using Decodable is so little. So now i am thinking of a way maybe i can create a parent class of these classes and `init` the context in it and just call `super.init()` in the subclasses of category and songs. But i really cannot do it. Or maybe there is a much simpler way. I will share the code of my classes here and the code where the error is happening.

```
struct CategoryData: Decodable {
    let data: [CategoryManagedObject]
}

@objc(CategoryManagedObject)
class CategoryManagedObject: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

    // MARK: - Core Data Managed Object
    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var imgUrl: String
    @NSManaged var coverPhotoBit64: String
    @NSManaged var jsonUrl: String
    @NSManaged var version: Int
    @NSManaged var order: Int
    @NSManaged var songs: NSSet?

    //var coreDataStack: CoreDataManager!

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, coverPhotoBit64, id, jsonUrl, version, order
        case imgUrl = "coverPhoto"
    }


    // MARK: - Decodable
    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //try super.init(from: decoder, type: "Categories")
        guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
        let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Categories", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                fatalError("FALIED TO DECODE CATEGORIES")
        }


        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        imgUrl = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .imgUrl)
        coverPhotoBit64 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .coverPhotoBit64)
        version = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .version)
        jsonUrl = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .jsonUrl)
        order = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .order)
//        if let sArray = songs.allObjects as? [Song] {
//            songs = try container.decode(sArray.self, forKey: .song)
//        }


    }

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CategoryManagedObject> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CategoryManagedObject>(entityName: "Categories")
    }

}


public extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    // Helper property to retrieve the context
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "managedObjectContext")
}

// MARK: Generated accessors for songs
extension CategoryManagedObject {

    @objc(addSongsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToSongs(_ value: Song)

    @objc(removeSongsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromSongs(_ value: Song)

    @objc(addSongs:)
    @NSManaged public func addToSongs(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeSongs:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromSongs(_ values: NSSet)

}



@objc(Song)
public class Song: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var artist: String
    @NSManaged var code: String
    @NSManaged var category: CategoryManagedObject

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, id, artist, code
    }

    // MARK: - Decodable
    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        guard let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
            let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Songs", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                fatalError("FALIED TO DECODE CATEGORIES")
        }


        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        artist = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .artist)
        code = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .code)


    }

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Song> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Song>(entityName: "Songs")
    }
}
```

This is where the crash happens because of two different context.

```
 func saveJsonSongsInDB(filename fileName: String, category: CategoryManagedObject) {

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: fileName)!)
            //let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.context!] = dbContext
            //decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.deferInsertion] = true
            coreDataStack.deleteAllRecords("Songs")
            let songs = try decoder.decode([Song].self, from: data)
            let s = NSSet(array: songs)
           // category.managedObjectContext?.insert(<#T##object: NSManagedObject##NSManagedObject#>)
           // dbContext.insert(category)
            //print("SONGS: \(songs)")
            category.addToSongs(s)  //----> CRASH

            try dbContext.save()
        } catch let err {
            print("error:\(err)")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all use **one** context, the context passed in the `JSONDEcoder`

- In `CategoryManagedObject` declare `songs` as non-optional native type

  ```
  @NSManaged var songs: Set<Song>
  ```
- Decode `songs` as `Set` (yes, this is possible) and set the category of each song to `self`

  ```
  songs = try container.decode(Set<Song>.self, forKey: .song)
  songs.forEach{ $0.category = self }
  ```

That's all. You don't have to set the inverse relationship in `CategoryManagedObject`

To insert the data you have to decode `[CategoryManagedObject]`

```
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.context!] = dbContext    
 coreDataStack.deleteAllRecords("Songs")
 _ = try decoder.decode([CategoryManagedObject].self, from: data)
```

Comment: This issue is that i don't have song data in the `json`of  category. I just have category `id` in the song data. So i get the categories from the server then download `english.json` file for each category of songs. For example i have 5 categories or let's say languages. So i get the `jsonUrl` in the category data and download it's `json` file and parse it and add the data to the related category and that was were the error happening. So the issue is now that i cannot parse songs in Category class because there is no such attribute in the `json` data of the categories.